# Long polling telegram with ReactPHP async

Tags: php, asynchronous, telegram-bot, long-polling, reactphp

I'm trying to do **long polling** with reactphp.
 
 
I have a function **getNotifications** that stay in long polling waiting a response from Telegram. 
 
 
This telegram api can hold the request open until **timeout** or 
can send a response **before** the end of the 50 seconds if there is a notification.
 
 
How I can recall getNotifications after a response from Telegram? 
Basically I want that getNotifications is called again when there is a response. 
 
 
This is my code, 
 thank you all

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Clue\React\Buzz\Browser;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use React\EventLoop\LoopInterface;

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();

$browser = new Browser($loop);

$method = "getUpdates";

$timeout = 50;

$params = [
    "offset" => 550495530,
    "limit" => 1000,
    "timeout" => $timeout
];

$bot_key = "your bot token";

$query = http_build_query($params);

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $bot_key . "/" . $method . "?" . $query;

$browser = $browser->withOptions(array(
    'timeout' => $timeout
));

function callback(){
    echo "done";
}

function getNotifications($url, $browser, LoopInterface $loop){
    $browser->get($url)->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) {
        // response received within 50 seconds. Telegram longpolling
        var_dump((string)$response->getBody());
        callback();
    });
}

function timer($start, LoopInterface $loop)
{
    //Timer only used to count seconds
    $loop->addPeriodicTimer(1.0, function ($timer) use (&$start, $loop) {
            echo "tick ". $start++ . "\n";
    });
}

timer(0, $loop);

getNotifications($url, $browser, $loop);

$loop->run();
```

Comment: do you examine cron jobs?

Comment: Thankyou but I don't want to use cron jobs. I want a php file with an event loop that in an async way check updates from telegram while doing other things like the timer in my code.

Comment: What is preventing you from calling the function again after the callback?

Comment: I don't have access to  $url, $browser, $loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find the solution. To pass parameter to the anonymous function I need to use the **use** keyword. Then inside the function I can access correctly the variables.

```
function getNotifications($url, $browser, LoopInterface $loop){
    $browser->get($url)->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($url, $browser,$loop) {
      // response received within 50 seconds. Telegram longpolling
      var_dump((string)$response->getBody());
      callback();
      getNotifications($url, $browser,$loop);
});
```

}